# what is wrong in this script? I am Getting HTTP error

Tags: python, html

Can someone please tell me why this script is not working an why am I gettint an HTTP error:

```
import sys
import bs4
import requests
import webbrowser
def search(productUrl):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0)'}
    res=requests.get(productUrl,headers=headers)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    linkedelement=soup.select('.r a')
    linkstoopen=min(5,len(linkedelement))
    for i in range(linkstoopen):
        webbrowser.open('https://google.co.in'+linkedelement[i].get('herf'))
sea=search('https://google.co.in/search?q='+''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: What HTTP error are you getting? Please add details to your post so we can help you.

Comment: The error is to do with your local connection. I have ran this script perfectly fine. Can you please edit to show what problem you are dealing with?

Comment: "E:\Pythons\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable for url: https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://google.co.in/search%3Fq%3D%27kumar%27&q=EgRn-QT5GPOp8d4FIhkA8aeDS1esovY_rWPDRgzEXnyWcgcEM_XsMgFy

Comment: The issue is not your code, that would be your home internet connection.

Comment: how can i resolve this,any suggestion?

Comment: Try making it run through a proxy, that way it isn't connecting through your home connection

Comment: I am new to python,can you tell me how to run this through proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying running it through a proxy. Make sure you edit the IP and Port.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import bs4
import requests
import webbrowser

def search(productUrl):
    http = "https://IP:PORT"
    https = "http://IP:PORT"

    proxy = { 
        "http"  : http, 
        "https" : https, 
    }

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0)'}
    res=requests.get(productUrl, headers=headers, proxies=proxy)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    linkedelement=soup.select('.r a')
    linkstoopen=min(5,len(linkedelement))
    for i in range(linkstoopen):
        webbrowser.open('https://google.co.in'+linkedelement[i].get('herf'))

sea=search('https://google.co.in/search?q='+''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```